The sum of two linear compact operators is a linear compact operator
I am trying to solve

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed vector space. Show that if $T_1,T_2\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ are compact operators, then $T_1+T_2\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is a compact operator$

I encountered this proof

$T\in \mathcal{L}(X, Y) $ is compact iff $T(\overline{B(0, 1) }) \subset Y$ is compact.
$(T_1+T_2)(\overline{B(0, 1) })=T_1(\overline{B(0, 1) })+T_2(\overline{B(0, 1) })$.
Now it follows from Compactness of $T_1$ and $T_2$ that $T_1+T_2$ is compact.

I could not understand this proof. First the definition for a compact operator $T$ is

$\overline{T(B(0,1))}$ is compact.

It seems to me that $T(\overline{B(0,1)})\subset \overline{T(B(0,1))}$.
Another problem with this proof is $(T_1+T_2)(B(0,1))\subset T_1(B(0,1))+T_2(B(0,1))$. We can conclude from this
$$\overline{(T_1+T_2)(B(0,1))}\subset \overline{T_1(B(0,1))+T_2(B(0,1))}$$
How do I proceed from here?


Are you quoting the question correctly?  $\mathcal L(X,Y)$ is often used to denote the bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$, not just the compact ones.

The bounded linear operator $T$ is compact if $\overline{T(B(0,1))}$ is compact.  $T(\overline{B(0,1)})$ is not required to be, and usually is not, compact.

The Cartesian product of two compact sets $\overline{T_1(B(0,1))} \times \overline{T_2(B(0,1))}$ is compact. $\overline{T_1(B(0,1))} + \overline{T_2(B(0,1))}$ is the image of this compact set under the continuous map $(s,t) \mapsto s+t$, and therefore is compact.



I forget to say compact operator. I think the proof in the post is not correct but it aligned with my original thought, I could not correct that proof.
